# Finding post content that begins with a specific character

Tags: wp-query, functions

If I want to find all posts where the very first character(s) of the post text / content (ie not the title) are

```
"<"
```

or

```
"<a"
```

How would I do so?

I tried these solutions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246263/fetch-posts-starting-with-alphabet-x

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39205088/querying-post-id-from-posts-starting-with-specific-character

but they did not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will probably work:

```
$results = array();

$allPosts = get_posts('post_type=post&numberposts=-1');
foreach ($allPosts as $aPost) {
    if ( substr($aPost->post_content, 0, 1) == '<' || substr($aPost->post_content, 0, 2) == '<a' )
        $results[] = $aPost->ID;
}

echo "<pre>".print_r($results,true)."</pre>";
```

**UPDATE:** but you should revisit the MySQL approach in the links you provided. This php method is somewhat wasteful as it gets everything, instead of only whats needed.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do this with simple MySQL query though? Selecting all posts and looping through them isn't very efficient approach, I guess.

Comment: you're right, mysql directly would be less waste. The links in the OP were using MySQL, for the same problem, and they didn't work for him - I just did a php alternative. I'll throw up a note about that.